# How to get xml elements which have childs with a certain tag and attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, elementtree

I want to find xml elements which have certain child elements. The child elements need to have a given tag and an attribute set to a specific value.

To give a concrete example (based on the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml)). I want to find all `country` elements which have a child element `neighbor` with attribute `name="Austria"`:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data = """<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
        <partner name="Austria"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Panama">
        <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
        <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
    </country>
</data>
"""

root = ET.fromstring(data)
```

What I've tried without success:

```
countries1 = root.findall('.//country[neighbor@name="Austria"]')
countries2 = root.findall('.//country[neighbor][@name="Austria"]')
countries3 = root.findall('.//country[neighbor[@name="Austria"]]')
```

which all give:

> SyntaxError: invalid predicate

---

Following solutions are obviously wrong, as too much elements are found:

```
countries4 = root.findall('.//country/*[@name="Austria"]')
countries5 = root.findall('.//country/[neighbor]')
```

where `countries4` contains all elements having an attribute `name="Austria"`, but including the `partner` element. `countries5` contains all elements which have *any* neighbor element as a child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to find all country elements which have a child element neighbor with attribute name="Austria"

see below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data = """<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
        <partner name="Austria"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Panama">
        <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
        <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
    </country>
</data>
"""

root = ET.fromstring(data)
countries_with_austria_as_neighbor = [c.attrib['name'] for c in root.findall('.//country') if
                                      'Austria' in [n.attrib['name'] for n in c.findall('neighbor')]]
print(countries_with_austria_as_neighbor)
```

output

```
['Liechtenstein']
```

Comment: I was so focused on resolving it with a single xpath expression, that I forgot all other possible ways. A list comprehension makes definitely sense here.

Answer (score 0):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data = """<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
        <partner name="Austria"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Panama">
        <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
        <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="dummy"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
    </country>
    
</data>
"""

root = ET.fromstring(data)
for x in root.findall(".//country/neighbor[@name='Austria']"):
    print(x.attrib)
```

Output:

```
{'name': 'Austria', 'direction': 'E'}
{'name': 'Austria', 'direction': 'dummy'}
```

`//` : `Selects all subelements, on all levels beneath the current element. For example, .//egg selects all egg elements in the entire tree.`

`[@attrib='value']` : `Selects all elements for which the given attribute has the given value. The value cannot contain quotes`

```
for x in root.find('.'):
    if x[0].attrib['name'] == 'Austria':
                   print(x.attrib['name'])
```

Output:
`Liechtenstein`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, your solution will give all neighbor elements with attribute `name="Austria"`. I am interested in country elements which have those elements as a child.

Comment: `".//country/neighbor[@name='Austria']"` this should work

Comment: This will also find neighbor elements, but not country elements.

Comment: I've added an extra `country tag`

Comment: we should use 2 `for loops` and i've updated..which will get you all tags with `[@name='Austria']`